# dynamically name the column in the dataTable with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I need to find the way to parse this data so that i can dynamically name the column based on the JSON

I am using jquery dataTable

```
[  
   {  
      "2":{  
         "Department Number":{  
            "column":"Department Number",
            "department":"100"
         }
      },
      "1":{  
         "Department Number":{  
            "column":"Department Number",
            "department":"200"
         },
          "Department Name":{  
               "column":"Department Name",
               "department":"STMS"
          }

      }
   }
]
```

so that all the data in the dataTable looks like this

```
id    department number    department name
2     100
1     200                  STMS
```

I am using the coldfusion and javascript .Here is the code for it

```
<cfoutput>var data=#serializeJSON(dataJSON.getDepatmentData())#;</cfoutput> 


var sysAdmin = new listDataHandler(); 
var dtColumns = [{title:"id"} 
                                ,{title:data[0]} 
                               ,{title:"data[1]"} 
               ] 


var oTable = $("#departmentTable").DataTable({columns:dtColumns,data:data.DATA 
 });
```

I hope i have explained myself well here

Comment: Why is the property named `column` in the first two objects, but it's called `question` in the last one?

Comment: sorry it is column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through all the objects in the JSON and create an array of the unique property names.

```
var colsObj = {};
for (id in data[0]) {
    for (prop in data[0][id]) {
        colsObj[prop] = true;
    }
}
var dtColumns = [{title: 'id'}].concat(Object.keys(colsObj).map(function(name) {
    return {title: name};
}));
```